# How to add Python libraries to Docker image

Tags: python, docker

Today I started working with Docker. So please bear with me. I'm not even sure if the title makes sense. I just installed Tensorflow using Docker and wanted to run a script. However, I got the following error saying that Matplotlib is not installed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tf_mlp_v3.py", line 3, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I used the following command to install Tensorflow

```
docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter
```

How can I now add other python libraries such as Matplotlib to that image?

Comment: There are a number of good videos on YouTube that will help you with Docker basics. Try this one, there are dozens more: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFl2mCHdv24

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To customize an image you generally want to create a new one using the existing image as a base. In Docker it is extremely common to create custom images when existing ones don't quite do what you want. By basing your images off public ones you can add your own customizations without having to repeat (or even know) what the base image does.

1. Add the necessary steps to a new **Dockerfile**.

   ```
   FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter

   RUN <extra install steps>
   COPY <extra files>
   ```

   `RUN` and `COPY` are examples of instructions you might use. `RUN` will run a command of your choosing such as `RUN pip install matplotlib`. `COPY` is used to add new files from your machine to the image, such as a configuration file.
2. Build and tag the new image. Give it a new name of your choosing. I'll call it `my-customized-tensorflow`, but you can name it anything you like.

   Assuming the `Dockerfile` is in the current directory, run `docker build`:

   ```
   $ docker build -t my-customized-tensorflow .
   ```
3. Now you can use `my-customized-tensorflow` as you would any other image.

   ```
   $ docker run my-customized-tensorflow
   ```

Comment: Where do I place the Dockerfile? Can you be more specific how to install, for example, Matplotlib? Is it just `RUN pip install matplotlib`? What comes after `COPY`? What exactly is `my-customized-tensorflow`? The new name of the image? Or a completely new image?

Comment: The Dockerfile goes wherever you want to put it. You might create a new directory called `my-customized-tensorflow` and put it in there, for instance. Up to you how you want to organize your files.

Comment: I have read that pip should be invoked with `python -m pip ...`, because `pip ...` might not point to the same version of python. Is that not preferred here, too?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the OP does not need to `COPY` extra files, so it would be a better answer with that line removed from the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your Dockerfile after pulling the image:

```
RUN python -m pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: Please add more context, where to add that instruction.

Comment: Where can I find my Dockerfile?

Comment: A dockerfile is a file you write. and you put that instruction in the dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options:

- Get into the container and install dependencies (be aware that this changes will be lost when recreating the container):

  ```
  docker exec <your-container-id> /bin/bash
  ```

  That should open an interactive bash. Then install the dependencies (pip or conda).
- Another alternative, is to add it during build time (of the image). That is adding the instruction `RUN` into a Dockerfile

All dependencies are installed using python default tools (i.e: pip, conda)

Comment: Modifying running containers is a bad habit. Stop the container and you lose your changes.

Comment: @JohnKugelman But you can use it nevertheless because there is `docker commit` which creates an image from already running container :)

Comment: Agree with both of you. In this context, a Docker newcomer whose main focus seems to be use tensorflow, I'm it is more valuable to make it work the simpler first. Then you can start learning deeper about Docker.

Comment: `docker commit` is another bad habit because you lose the ability to recreate the image. I agree it's simpler, but bad habits are always simpler, no? They'd hardly be attractive otherwise. Let's not teach newcomers bad habits.

Comment: Again, depends on the context. Adding more complexity that required is not a good practice neither.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use '--user' to store the packages mounted folders

```
mkdir /path/to/local
mkdir /path/to/cache
```

Add these option to the docker command

```
--mount type=bind,source=/path/to/local,target=/.local --mount type=bind,source=/path/to/cache,target=/.cache
```

Then you can install packages using

```
pip install --user pandas
```

The packages will then be persistent without having to build and restart you docker every time.