# Installing Python libraries in the Visual Studio Code container

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code

I can edit python code in a folder located in a Docker Volume. I use Visual Studio Code and in general lines it works fine.

The only problem that I have is that the libraries (such as pandas and numpy) are not installed in the container that Visual Studio creates to mount the volume, so I get warning errors.

How to install these libraries in Visual Studio Code container?

** UPDATE **

This is my application `Dockerfile`, see that the libraries are included in the image, not the volume:

```
FROM daskdev/dask

RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda create -p /pyenv -y
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda install -p /pyenv scikit-learn flask waitress gunicorn \
    pytest apscheduler matplotlib pyodbc -y
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda install -p /pyenv -c conda-forge dask-ml pyarrow -y
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda install -p /pyenv pip -y
RUN /pyenv/bin/pip install pydrill
```

And the application is started with `docker compose`:

```
version: '3'

services:   

  web:
    image: img-python
    container_name: cont_flask
    volumes:
      - vol_py_code:/code
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    working_dir: /code
    entrypoint:
      - /pyenv/bin/gunicorn
    command:
      - -b 0.0.0.0:5000
      - --reload
      - app.frontend.app:app
```

Comment: It would be useful if you showed your Dockerfile and how you run the container

Comment: Please [edit] to provide details on how people can reproduce your setup, especially this part of "*the container that Visual Studio creates to mount the volume*".

Comment: @GinoMempin VSC has a Docker plugin that let's you explore a volume. When you add that plugin you can see the list of volumes, then you can right click the volume to explore it. I have no idea how VSC creates the volume, I just see it in Docker.

Answer (score 1):

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial
In the VScode documentation, there is a section called "Install and use packages" under the python tutorial. I think that will explain it to you.
Edit:
Have you added it to your dockerfile? Like:
RUN pip install pandas
Try to look at the answer to this question and see if it helps:
[How to add Python libraries to Docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58191215/how-to-add-python-libraries-to-docker-image)
Edit2:
It seems like VSC are using the local environment, when it creates a container, and there isn't a devcontainer.json file.
I think you need to either install the libraries in your local environment or set up a development container in VSC:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/create-dev-container
Microsoft have a GitHub repo with development container templates:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers
If you already have set up a development container, can you please add your devcontainer.json file to your question, so it is possible to look at it?

Comment: That link talks about installing the packages in a non-container machine, I tried to follow it but it is not clear the differences, so I couldn't make it work

Comment: @ps0604 I have edited the answer with a link to a similar question, hope it can help.

Comment: the docker file that I use has all the libraries as I can run it without any issues. That docker file has mounted a volume with Python code. That volume is the one that I open with Visual Studio Code, but since the python libraries are in the container built with my Dockerfile and not the container built by Visual Studio Code to access the volume, those libraries are missing. So the question is how to make these libraries accessible to the Visual Studio Code container that's created automatically when you open the volume.

Comment: Please see the updated question with Dockerfile and Docker compose The problem is that Visual Studio Code creates automatically a container. Sometimes it reuses the container, sometimes it creates a new one. So how to install the libraries?

Comment: It's using the right environment, VSC is creating a new container with python installed for syntax checking but this container doesn't have the libraries declared in the code, therefore there are warnings that these libraries cannot be found

Comment: Okay. I think you need to look at the devcontainer.json file. Are the libraries loaded into VSC from there?

Comment: @ps0604 I have edited my answer. Try to make a dev container and see if it solves the problem, or if you already have one, can you please share the devcontainer.json file?

Comment: what is this `devcontainer.json` file?

Comment: The VSC container configuration are stored in the devcontainer.json file. Try to look at the link to the documentation in my 2nd edit, it explains how to make the file. There is also a section on how to use it with docker compose. I think if you look at the documentation, you should be able to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tutorial for docker: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-python#_add-docker-files-to-the-project

In your case I think you should just put the extra packages to generated `requirements.txt`. If that does not work out of the box, you can modify dockerfile extending the microsoft default python image.

[image]

Comment: I'm not creating or selecting any Dockerfiles, just open the Docker volume with VSC. There are no Dockerfiles or  `requirements.txt` files to edit.

Comment: Maybe you can edit your code inside the dev container with you volume attached? You can also have dev docker compose which overrides the prod one, that would probably be best practice. Why do you need to use it as described?

Comment: The problem with editing the dev container is that it is temporary. VSC creates new containers all the time. That's why I say they are temporary.

Comment: It should not matter if you describe all you need in you recipes Dockerfile, than new container is build as is should be at the end.

Comment: where is this recipes Dockerfile located?

Comment: Green little icon in bottom left corner -> open folder in container and pick what you like -> .devcontainer folder containing dockerfile is generated there.

Comment: so I need to create a folder, put my Dockerfile in there, then go to the bottom left corner, open that folder, and the libraries of the Dockerfile will be in the environment?

Comment: I updated my answer and this is what is generated with that option.

Answer (score 0):

The warnings originate from using a different python interpreter for your Docker volume and Visual Studio Code.

This can be solved by directing the python interpreter to the one in your Docker volume. Clicking one the python interpreter in the bottom left of VS Code ("Python 3.8.0" in the image below) gives you the option to change the path. Enter the path to the Python in your docker volume.

[image]

Edit: the path could be something like `/pyenv/bin/python`.